# Login form and Registration form without using database

Tags: c#, forms

My Instructor gave me and my classmates some three activities and of those activities is to make a simple login form with a registration form without using database (well its obvious that we need to do this activity before proceeding with database).....

Here is the codes:
Form1:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string Username;
        string Password;
        string NAME;
        string Age;

        Form2 Frm = new Form2();
//Here is where you get the value of the String from Form2
        public void PassValue(string strValue)
        {
            Username = strValue;
        }
        public void PassAnotherValue(string strValue2)
        {
            Password = strValue2;
        }
        public void PassAnotherValueAgain(string strValue3)
        {
            NAME = strValue3;
        }
        public void PassAnotherValueAgainAndAgain(string strvalue4)
        {
            Age = strvalue4;
        }
//------------------------------------------------------------------
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LoginUserNameTB.Text))    
            {     
                MessageBox.Show("Please input proper Username...!");  
            } 
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LoginPasswordTB.Text))    
            {    
                MessageBox.Show("Please input proper Password...!");
            }    
            else if ((LoginUserNameTB.Text != Username) && (LoginPasswordTB.Text != Password)) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome" + NAME + "!");    
            }
            else if ((LoginUserNameTB.Text == Username) && (LoginPasswordTB.Text == Password))  
            {  
                MessageBox.Show("Please input proper Username and/or Password...!");
            }
        }

        private void RegisterBtn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Frm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
//Form2 has four textboxes, four labels, and a button
            private void RegisterBtn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {  
                Form1 obj1 = new Form1();
                Form1 obj2 = new Form1();
                Form1 obj3 = new Form1(); 
                Form1 obj4 = new Form1();   
                Form1 obj5 = new Form1();

        //This is where you pass the String value back to Form1
                    obj1.PassValue(RegUserNameTB.Text);
                    obj2.PassAnotherValue(RegPasswordTB.Text); 
                    obj3.PassAnotherValueAgain(NTB.Text);     
                    obj4.PassAnotherValueAgainAndAgain(ATB.Text);


                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(NTB.Text) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ATB.Text) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RegUserNameTB.Text) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RegPasswordTB.Text))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please enter the following:" + "\n" + "Name" + "\n" + "Age" + "\n" + "\n" + "UserName" + "\n" + "Password");
                    }   
                Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now to the problem of this program.....
The program is working just fine and every time I enter a Username and a Password it worked but the value of the 'NAME' is missing and every time I clicked the Register Button it will only perform its action once and never again (probably needs an Exception).... And to sum it up our Instructor told us that the user will have a limit of 3 of entering its username and password and after that the program will close.... Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you creating 5 `Form1()` objects?

Answer (score 3):

I can see that you are trying to store some information related to an user each time Registeration form (Form2) is called.

These properties :

```
    string Username;
    string Password;
    string NAME;
    string Age;
```

should be stored in a class not in the form (Form1 as in your code).
I suggest making a simple class with these fields :

```
class User
{
    // make those fields public for accessibility
    public string Username;
    public string Password;
    public string NAME;
    public string Age;

    public User(string Username, string Password, string NAME, string Age)
    {
        // assign each fields with arguments from constructor
        this.Username = Username;
        this.Password = Password;
        this.NAME = NAME;
        this.Age = Age;
    }
}
```

Without a database, let's create a list to store each "User"

```
class User
{
    // Dont forget to add // using System.Collections.Generic;
    // on top of the file otherwise List<> would not be available
    public static List<User> UserList = new List<User>();

    // make those fields public for accessibility
    public string Username;
    public string Password;
    public string NAME;
    public string Age;

    public User(string Username, string Password, string NAME, string Age)
    {
        // assign each fields with arguments from constructor
        this.Username = Username;
        this.Password = Password;
        this.NAME = NAME;
        this.Age = Age;
    }
}
```

To add new User to the UserList, make a new method to handle it inside our User class

```
class User
{
    // Dont forget to add // using System.Collections.Generic;
    // on top of the file otherwise List<> would not be available
    public static List<User> UserList = new List<User>();

    // make those fields public for accessibility
    public string Username;
    public string Password;
    public string NAME;
    public string Age;

    public User(string Username, string Password, string NAME, string Age)
    {
        // assign each fields with arguments from constructor
        this.Username = Username;
        this.Password = Password;
        this.NAME = NAME;
        this.Age = Age;
    }

    public static void AddUserToList(User user)
    {
        UserList.Add(user);
    }
}
```

Each time an user want to register, you can handle the button click event like this :

```
    private void RegisterBtn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // check for valid input first
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(NTB.Text) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ATB.Text) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RegUserNameTB.Text) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RegPasswordTB.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the following:" + "\n" + "Name" + "\n" + "Age" + "\n" + "\n" + "UserName" + "\n" + "Password");
        }
        else
        {
            User user = new User(RegUserNameTB.Text, RegPasswordTB.Text, NTB.Text, ATB.Text);
            User.AddUserToList(user);
        }
        Close();
    }
```

Now you can implement your "Login" logic by iterating through the UserList, check if user inputs match any User in the list